# Dropdown menu scroll on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, autoscroll

I have a dropdown menu at the bottom of my page.  When the user clicks it, I want the page to automatically scroll down to the bottom of the menu contents.  Right now, the user has to manually scroll down the page when the menu is opened.  I tried to use anchors for this, initially, but that breaks the dropdown functionality, so I'd like to keep it as a button.

I included a test anchor in my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MReBCwuLlo8OLIXp5yMB?p=preview), which works as expected.  I also don't understand why the dropdown content is appearing after the test `div`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bottom btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"
   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Themes <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Teal</li>
            <li>Gray</li>
            <li>Plum</li>
            <li>Violet</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="test">test</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bottom {
    bottom: -890px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

  $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click',function(){
    var height = $(document).height();
    $(window).scrollTop(height);
  });
});
```